# Reply for yesterday message

Tags: sentence-construction

Someone sent a message to me after I left the office yesterday. He was expecting an instant reply. How can I write to him today to convey that I was not here and now this is my response?

Answer (score 3):

I was not in my office yesterday when you left me a message. Here is my response.

*Response*